# Kindle Fire Utility Not Installing Google Apps

Tags: rooting

So I recently rooted my Kindle Fire using the Kindle Fire Utility, the root has seemingly installed correctly but when I go to install the google apps I get errors and when I double checked the apps are definitely not installed on the kindle
the error I'm getting is here

```
Error:
cannot find archive
su: permission denied
su: permission denied
su: permission denied
can't find 'apps\data\GoogleServicesFramework.apk' to install
can't find 'apps\data\com.gau.go.launcherex-1.apk' to install
can't find 'apps\data\com.facebook.katana-1.apk' to install
can't find 'apps\data\com.google.android.apps.googlevoice-1.apk' to install
can't find 'apps\data\com.google.android.apps.plus-1.apk' to install
can't find 'apps\data\SyncSettings.apk' to install
can't find 'apps\data\Calendar.apk' to install
cannot stat 'apps\system\vending.apk': No such file or directory
cannot stat 'apps\system\GoogleCalendarSyncAdapter.apk': No such file or directory
cannot stat 'apps\system\GoogleContactsSyncAdapter.apk': No such file or directory
su: permission denied
su: permission denied
su: permission denied
rm failed for /data/local/vending.apk, No such file or directory
rm failed for /data/local/GoogleCalendarSyncAdapter.apk, No such file or directory
rm failed for /data/local/GoogleContactsSyncAdapter.apk, No such file or directory
su: permission denied
su: permission denied
su: permission denied
```

[image]

I'm assuming this means that the su didt work or needs addition permission but I have SU set to "always allow"

Comment: The tool(s) you are using seem to be pretty old (at least the 7zip version is heavily outdated  and insecure). And the script seems to be designed bad as it does not stop after the first error `cannot find archive`. Check the script what it tries to do that causes this error and fix it. I would assume it is trying to download a OpenGApps package which fails so that of course nothing can be installed.